# gem install ffi-yajl causes `undefined method include_path` error

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am getting the following error while trying to install ffi-yajl

```
Using berkshelf 4.3.3
Installing ffi-yajl 2.4.0 with native extensions
STDERR: Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-yajl-2.4.0/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20210628-15489-1ggpxn5.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.5
extconf.rb:9:in <main>': undefined method include_path' for Libyajl2:Module
(NoMethodError)
Did you mean? include

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

It seems to be this line that is failing:

https://github.com/chef/ffi-yajl/blob/master/ext/ffi_yajl/ext/encoder/extconf.rb#L9

unfortunately my knowledge of Ruby is very limited and I don't know if 'include_path' should be defined and if it should then why it is not defined.

Thanks

Comment: What's your OS?, according with the error it seems that you need a C compiler installed, check if you have gcc. The library is written in C https://lloyd.github.io/yajl/

Comment: I am running it on Debian Buster on a raspberry pi. I am pretty sure I have gcc, but will check.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.
Here are the steps:

1. sudo apt remove ruby
2. Install ruby https://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-latest-stable-centos/#
3. try gem install again

Source: https://github.com/chef/ffi-yajl/issues/91